# html agree button is supposed to close when button is pressed. (it will not close)

Tags: html, css

```js
function closePopup() {
        // Close the popup by setting its display property to "none"
            document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Hi there!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/xp.css@0.2.3/dist/98.css"          />
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="popup" style="margin: 32px; width: 250px; text-align: center; border: 5px;">
          <div class="title-bar">
            <div class="title-bar-text">
              Legal agreement
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="window-body">
            <p>you hereby consent to blah blah blah.</p>
            </div>
            <section id="button" style="justify-content: flex-end">
              <button  onclick="closePopup" >ACCEPT</button>
          </section>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was attempting to make a TOS agreement that closes after being agreed to but my button seems to not work. Im also attempting to make it look like a old windows computer window hence the CSS im using. This is my first time using HTML so go easy on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `class="popup"` to id="popup" since you are using `getElementById`.

Also your button should be `<button onclick="closePopup()" >ACCEPT</button>`

```js
function closePopup() {
   // Close the popup by setting its display property to "none"
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hi there!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/xp.css@0.2.3/dist/98.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="popup" style="margin: 32px; width: 250px; text-align: center; border: 5px;">
      <div class="title-bar">
        <div class="title-bar-text">
          Legal agreement
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="window-body">
        <p>you hereby consent to blah blah blah.</p>
        </div>
        <section id="button" style="justify-content: flex-end">
          <button onclick="closePopup()" >ACCEPT</button>
      </section>
    </div>
```